# Error while trying to download using wget

Tags: server

```
Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authentication Required
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

this is what shown while trying to download using wget..what is it??how to get my downloads right??

Comment: You appear to be behind a proxy server that requires authentication. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a non SSL link for example your's might be `https://foo.com/something/main.txt` but try to be like `http://foo.com/something/main.txt`

Or Check your Network Settings for Proxy, do you need proxy?